# Scrollbar not clickable/draggable

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a small issue on a website, where a block inside the website has overflow:scroll with a set height, this scrollbar has got some custom webkit elements.

The issue is while you can scroll, you can't drag or click on the scrollbar. I tried to force it back to default but that didn't seem to fix the issue. I'm wondering what it could be, or if that is a regular feature of overflow:scroll inside an already scrolling website.

Please see the issue here: [removed] and scroll to the bottom to the 'Mini 700 Spare Parts …' header, all the spare parts are in the scrollable area I described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an overlaying pseudo element that you need to remove.
On your style.css, line 332, delete this CSS rule:

```
.mpcth-sidebar-left .mpcth-use-advance-colors #mpcth_main_container:before, .mpcth-sidebar-right .mpcth-use-advance-colors #mpcth_main_container:before { content: ''; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 200%; height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Thanks that was it, how did you find it so quickly? I normally have no issues finding these type of bugs.

Comment: using the inspect tool and hovering on the place that has the problem :)